# Por que al insertar datos en mi base de datos esta se inserta de otra forma? MYSQ PHP

Tags: php, sql

la unica duda es que al insertar omeprazole capsules 7's, al ejecutar la sentencia esta se inserta asi en la base de datos omeprazole capsules 7\'s, apareciendo un , por que pasa esto?

```
public static function registerproduct($type , $name, $quantity_box, $box_pallet) {

    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `name`=:name");
    $query->execute(["name"=>$name]);
    $result = $query->rowCount();   

    if ($result == 1) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        $query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `products` (name, quantity_box, boxes_pallet, type, register_day) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())");
        return $result = $query->execute([$name, $quantity_box, $box_pallet, $type]);
    }
}
```

limpio las variables antes de insertarlas con:

```
 htmlentities(addslashes($var));
```

no se si eso tenga algo que ver

Answer (score 2):

Eso ocurre porque [`addslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.addslashes.php) :

> Devuelve un string con barras invertidas delante de los caracteres que
> necesitan ser escapados. Estos caracteres son la comilla simple (`'`),
> comilla doble (`"`), barra invertida (`\`) y `NUL` (el byte `NULL`).

Dado que estás usando consultas preparadas, no necesitas:

- Ni usar `addslashes()`
- Ni usar `htmlentities()`

**Las consultas preparadas de por sí te blindarán contra intentos de inyección**. Si quisieras mostrar en pantalla lo que hay en `$var`, entonces sí podrías filtrar (para mostrar en pantalla, no para insertar), por lo ya dicho. Entonces para la inserción puedes pasar el dato sin filtrarlo.

### Una nota sobre optimización y estandarización

Viendo que usas [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) para saber si una consulta `SELECT` trae filas, voy a citar una parte de la documentación al respecto:

> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement
> asociado fue una sentencia `SELECT`, algunas bases de datos podrían
> devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
> este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos
> y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

Eso significa que **`rowCount()` no siempre es un camino seguro para saber si una consulta trae filas**.

El camino más seguro es siempre usar una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` y, en caso de que necesites los datos de esa consulta, puedes llenar un conjunto de resultados y luego hacer una verificación sobre dicho objeto.

Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar [la mejor guía de PDO del mundo](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count), gracias a ella aprendí a a manejarme adecuadamente con esta API.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es por eso que dices, la función addslashes() te escapa ciertos caracteres, incluyendo `'` con un slash `\`
Pero como estás usando prepared statements, y los parámetros los marcas con `?` o con `:nombre` , no es necesario que utilices addslashes o htmlentities.

Comment: muchas gracias, uso addslashes y htmlentities para buena practica solamente xD